# WP Post Template - Templates in own folder

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, templates

I am using the plugin: WP Post Template which allows me to use templates for custom post types.

At present the plugin watches the **theme root directory** for pages with:

```
<?php
/**
* WP Post Template:  Template Name
*/
?>
```

I am trying to edit the plugin so I can store my template files in their own sub directory. Looking at the plugin code I think that I have found the line of code that controls where to watch for files but am having trouble modifying it

```
$base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) );
```

the folder I am trying to watch would be: **/lp/**

This code changes directory but i get white screen of death when viewing page

```
$base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory().'/lp/'), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory().'/lp/') );
```

My only guess is there is something more in the plugin code that needs editing

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP Post Template
Plugin URI: www.dotsquares.com
Description: This plugin allows theme authors to create a post tempate as well as page template for the single post.
Author: Dotsquares
Version: 1.0
Author URI: www.dotsquares.com
*/
add_action('add_meta_boxes','wp_add_post_custom_template');
add_action('save_post','wp_save_custom_post_template',10,2);
add_filter('single_template','wp_get_custom_post_template_for_template_loader');
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wp_add_post_custom_template' );
//define('DEF_POST','nutrition_article');

//register functon name for install plugin
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'wp_custom_post_template_activate');
function wp_custom_post_template_activate() {
    add_option ( 'wp_custom_post_template','post');
}

//register functon name for uninstall plugin
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wp_custom_post_template_deactivate' );
function wp_custom_post_template_deactivate() {
    //delete otion when plugin deactivated
    delete_option ( 'wp_custom_post_template');
}

function custom_post_template_css() {
        // add css files
        wp_register_style('wp-custom-style', plugins_url('/css/myStyle.css',__FILE__ ));
        wp_enqueue_style('wp-custom-style');
        //add js files
}
add_action( 'admin_init','custom_post_template_css');

if ( is_admin() )
{
    // add link to admin menu
    add_action('admin_menu', 'wp_post_template_admin_menu');
    function wp_post_template_admin_menu()
    {
        add_menu_page( 'WP Post Template', 'WP Post Template', 'manage_options', 'post_template_setting', 'wp_post_template_setting',plugins_url('ico.png',__FILE__ ));
    }
}
function wp_post_template_setting(){
    _e('<h2>WP Custom Post Template</h2>');
    include('_form.php');
}
function wp_add_post_custom_template($postType) {

    if(get_option('wp_custom_post_template') == ''){ //get option value
        $postType_title = 'post';
        $postType_arr[] = $postType_title;
    }else{
        $postType_title = get_option('wp_custom_post_template');
        $postType_arr = explode(',',$postType_title);
    }
    if(in_array($postType, $postType_arr)){
        add_meta_box(
                'postparentdiv',
                __('Template'),
                'wp_custom_post_template_meta_box',
                $postType,
                'side',
                'core'
        );
    }
}
function wp_custom_post_template_meta_box($post) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'page' && 0 != count( wp_get_post_custom_templates() ) ) {
        $template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',true);
    ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_template"><?php _e('Post Template') ?></label>
        <select name="post_template" id="post_template">
            <option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
            <?php wp_custom_post_template_dropdown($template); ?>
        </select>
    <?php
    }
}?>
<?php
function wp_get_post_custom_templates() {
  if(function_exists('wp_get_themes')){
        $themes = wp_get_themes();
    }else{
        $themes = get_themes();
    }
    $theme = get_option( 'template' );
  $templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
  $post_templates = array();

  if ( is_array( $templates ) ) {
    $base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) );

    foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
      $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);
      if ($basename != 'functions.php') {
        // don't allow template files in subdirectories
        if ( false !== strpos($basename, '/') )
          continue;

        $template_data = implode( '', file( $template ));

        $name = '';
        if ( preg_match( '|WP Post Template:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name ) )
          $name = _cleanup_header_comment($name[1]);

        if ( !empty( $name ) ) {
          $post_templates[trim( $name )] = $basename;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $post_templates;
}

function wp_custom_post_template_dropdown( $default = '' ) {
  $templates = wp_get_post_custom_templates();
  ksort( $templates );
  foreach (array_keys( $templates ) as $template )
    : if ( $default == $templates[$template] )
      $selected = " selected='selected'";
    else
      $selected = '';
  echo "\n\t<option value='".$templates[$template]."' $selected>$template</option>";
  endforeach;
}

function wp_save_custom_post_template($post_id,$post) {
  if ($post->post_type !='page' && !empty($_POST['post_template']))
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',$_POST['post_template']);
}

function wp_get_custom_post_template_for_template_loader($template) {
  global $wp_query;
  $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  if ($post) {
    $post_template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_post_template',true);

    if (!empty($post_template) && $post_template!='default')
      $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/{$post_template}";
  }

  return $template;
}
?>
```

Comment: there is another call to `get_stylesheet_directory()` almost at the end

Answer (score 1):

Use php dot notation.
Try:

```
$my_templates = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lp/';
$base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), $my_templates );
```

Comment: Same trail of thought as my own, /lp/ must be added to both get_stylesheet_directory & get_template_directory though